# How to stream audio from Google Docs (API)?

Tags: audio, stream, google-docs-api

Is there a way to stream audio from Google Docs (API)? MP3, AAC, etc..

Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No

Long answer: It's going to be very messy indeed. At best you're going to have to download the file and play it, streaming is going to be difficult as docs isn't designed for it. Have a read of http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Docs/thread?tid=1cd4f518b887618b&hl=en